# Grails "max" subquery with an association, to get only the latest of a hasMany

Tags: grails, grails-orm

The simplified domain model:
'Txn' (as in Transaction) hasMany 'TxnStatus'.  TxnStatus has a dateTime

This is a legacy mapping so I cant change the DB, the mapping on Txn:

```
  static mapping = { 
    txnStatus column: 'MessageID', ignoreNotFound: true, fetch: 'join'
  }
```

I need to get Txns based on a number of dynamically built criteria, currently using GORM's 'where' query, it works well; BUT I need to also get only the **latest** txnStatus.

Tried:

```
def query = Txn.where {
   txnStatus { dateTime == max(dateTime) }    
}
```

gives:  `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.criterion.DetachedCriteria cannot be cast to java.util.Date`

also tried:

```
 def query = Txn.where {
       txnStatus.dateTime == max(txnStatus.dateTime)    
    }
```

which gives:

```
Compilation Error: ... 
            Cannot use aggregate function max on expressions "txnStatus.dateTime"
```

At this stage I am thinking of changing to HQL...any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There was a question a couple of days ago very similar to this.  It appears that using where queries with a 'max' subquery doesn't work well with ==

The OP was able to get it to work with < and worked around it that way.  Looking at the docs on where queries has not helped me figure this one out.

Here is a really wild guess -

```
    Txn.where {
        txnStatus  {
          dateTime == property(dateTime).of { max(dateTime) }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! You put me on the right track, who would expect an issue with ==  .  The answer is 2-fold, use a >= and put the where in a new block, eg not with an && of another where closure, eg:query = query.where {
            txnStatus  {                
                dateTime >=  max(dateTime)
            }
        }    Though this doesnt actually solve my problem exactly as it only selects the max date from the whole table not for each Txn