# GORM query to find the most recent of an entry

Tags: ajax, grails, grails-orm

New to how the ORM works so bear with me.  I have a domain class

```
class MyClass()
{
    String myName
    Date mydate
}
```

I have bootstrapped a couple of examples with the same string and different dates. Then in my gsp I do an ajax call to a controller method

```
def MyAjaxCall
{
    def classes = MyClass.findAll()
}
```

How can I change this so I only return unique `myName` that have the most recent `mydate`?  Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610338/grails-max-subquery-with-an-association-to-get-only-the-latest-of-a-hasmany

Comment: problem is mine doesn't have a hasMany

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something on the following lines:

```
def classes = MyClass.createCriteria().list {
    projections {
        property("id")
        groupProperty("myName")
        max("mydate")
    }
}
```

and then get MyClass instances:

```
def latestClasses = results?.collect{MyClass.read(it[0])}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
def classes = MyClass.withCriteria {
    projections {
        property "myName"
    }
    maxResults(1)
    order("mydate", "desc")
}
```

Comment: This works but either gives one result or all results, I want to have it so if there are multiple entries of myName = "Bob" then it only spits back the most recent